# What's the most efficient way to write multiple WP_Queries on a page?

Tags: php

This is a follow-up to my previous post regarding multiple categories/posts on one page.

Currently, I have a page filled with multiple loops of each category of a custom post type. The problem is that the code is becoming a bit much to edit and organize. Here's a small example of the multiple categories I have:

```
$stratocaster_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'diagram',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'diagram-category', // Taxonomy slug
            'terms' => 'stratocaster-wiring-diagrams', // Taxonomy term slug
            'field' => 'slug',    // Taxonomy field
        )
    )
);

$telecaster_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'diagram',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'diagram-category', // Taxonomy slug
            'terms' => 'telecaster-wiring-diagrams', // Taxonomy term slug
            'field' => 'slug',    // Taxonomy field
        )
    )
);
$misc_fender_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'diagram',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'diagram-category', // Taxonomy slug
            'terms' => 'misc-fender-wiring-diagrams', // Taxonomy term slug
            'field' => 'slug',    // Taxonomy field
        )
    )
);

$stratocaster_query = new WP_Query($stratocaster_args);
$telecaster_query = new WP_Query($telecaster_args);
$misc_fender_query = new WP_Query($misc_fender_args);

?>

<div class="blog-archive">

    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/page', 'header'); ?>

    <?php page_wrapper_open('wiring-diagrams'); ?>



    <?php

    /**Begin Wiring Diagram Results */

    /**Strat */

    if ($stratocaster_query->have_posts()) :

        echo '<h2 class="main-heading gold-line">STRATOCASTER WIRING DIAGRAMS:</h2>';

        echo '<div class="wiring-diagram-results grid-4">';

        while ($stratocaster_query->have_posts()) :
            $stratocaster_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'wiring-diagram');
        endwhile;

        echo '</div>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

    /**Telecaster */

    if ($telecaster_query->have_posts()) :

        echo '<h2 class="main-heading gold-line">TELECASTER WIRING DIAGRAMS:</h2>';

        echo '<div class="wiring-diagram-results grid-4">';

        while ($telecaster_query->have_posts()) :
            $telecaster_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'wiring-diagram');
        endwhile;

        echo '</div>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

    /**Misc Fender */

    if ($misc_fender_query->have_posts()) :

        echo '<h2 class="main-heading gold-line">MISC. FENDER WIRING DIAGRAMS:</h2>';

        echo '<div class="wiring-diagram-results grid-4">';

        while ($misc_fender_query->have_posts()) :
            $misc_fender_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'wiring-diagram');
        endwhile;

        echo '</div>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

........etc.
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this to manage the code a little better? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: can you be more specific than efficient? Efficient to type? Efficient as in performance? Easy to read? Your question needs to be specific enough that people can write factual answers that thoroughly and completely solve the question, not just opinions. Remember this is not a discussion forum, it's a Question Answer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the query configs into one config array and loop that for querying the posts and rendering the content sections. Inside the content section partial you'd have another loop for the posts.

The magic ingredient here is the third `$args` parameter you can use with `get_template_part()`. Use it to pass data to the partial file.

```
$configs = array(
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'post_type' => 'diagram',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'diagram-category',
          'terms' => 'stratocaster-wiring-diagrams',
          'field' => 'slug',
        )
      )
    ),
    'template_name' => 'wiring-diagram',
    'heading' => 'Some heading text',
  ),
  // more configs...
);

foreach ( $configs as $config ) {
  $config['query'] = new WP_Query( $config['query'] );
  if ( ! $config['query']->posts ) {
    continue;
  }
  
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-section', null, $config );
}
```

Section partial,

```
<h2 class="main-heading gold-line"><?php echo esc_html( $args['heading'] ); ?></h2>
<div class="wiring-diagram-results grid-4">
  <?php
    while( $args['query']->have_posts() ) {
      $args['query']->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', $args['template_name'] );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div>
```

The config array could also be placed into a separate file or function and not to have it hard-coded on the template file.

Comment: Yes, this is really what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Split your code into smaller parts. For example, you can use a separate template part for each loop.

The [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function might be a good choice in your case.